# The buildnumber-maven-plugin is returning UNKNOW branch name

Tags: maven, mercurial

I'm using mercruial and buildnumber-maven-plugin 1.4.
And this plugin is able to return SCM branch information with `${scmBranch}` command according [documentaion](http://www.mojohaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/create-mojo.html).
However command `${scmBranch}` return value UNKNOW.
What i need to do to get branch name information from buildnumber-maven-plugin?

My pom.xml:

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.6</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
              </manifest>
              <manifestEntries>
                <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                <SCM-Build>${scmBranch}</SCM-Build>
              </manifestEntries>
            </archive>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>create</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <doCheck>false</doCheck>
          <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
          <scmBranchPropertyName>true</scmBranchPropertyName>


        </configuration>
      </plugin>
```

Comment: Do you have Git installed on your machine?

Comment: @Tunaki yes, i have.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be that you cannot setup `buildnumber-maven-plugin` with `mecrurial` so that `${scmBranch}` will be returning branch name, [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894281/the-buildnumber-maven-plugin-is-returning-unknown-for-the-scmbranch) is SO issue where is said that version 1.2 of this plugin works only with SVN branch information. I don't think it is changed in version 1.4. Moreover [here](https://github.com/mojohaus/buildnumber-maven-plugin/issues/53) is fresh report on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Create a separate `<plugins> tag </plugins>` outside of `<pluginManagement>` and put the buildnumber maven plugin separately in there. That's what did it for me, don't ask why.